# How can I put a currencyformatter in a flex datagrid column?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, datagrid, adobe, format

I need to format the column with a currency formatter. I know how to do currency formatting I just need an example on how to implement it into the datagrid column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to use an `itemRenderer`. Just use a `labelFunction`. Example:

**The DataGridColumn:**

```
<mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Total Cost" dataField="TotalCost" labelFunction="LabelFormatter"/>
```

**LabelFormatter label function:**

```
protected function LabelFormatter(item:Object, column:DataGridColumn):String
{
  var returnLabel:String = "";
  var header:String = column.headerText;

  switch (header)
  {                 
    case "Total Cost":
      returnLabel = currencyFormat.format(item.TotalCost.toString());
      break;
  }

  return returnLabel;
}
```

**The Currency Formatter:**

```
<mx:CurrencyFormatter id="currencyFormat" precision="2" />
```

Comment: It seems like there is no need for the switch statement. LabelFormatter() is only applied to a single column of the datagrid. Every time it is called, column.headerText is equal to "Total Cost".

Comment: @Eric In this case you are absolutely right. I had used this same function to re-format the labels for several columns in my production application which is why the switch statement is in there. I removed the other columns for the sake of clarity and brevity.

Answer (score 1):

Or:

```
private function formatarValor(item:Object, coluna:DataGridColumn):String{
    return realFormatter.format(item[coluna.dataField]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An ActionScript based answer that doesn't require defining an additional function:

```
var currencyFormatter:CurrencyFormatter = new CurrencyFormatter();
var gridCol:GridColumn = new GridColumn("My Money");
gridCol.dataField = "amount";
gridCol.formatter = currencyFormatter;
```

From the [Adobe docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/gridClasses/GridColumn.html#labelFunction), the labelFunction property is useful for performing more complex tasks, such as combining two fields from the data provider into one column. But for a simple task such as formatting currency values, the above code is sufficient.